# unable to run query against BigQuery - permission error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a `IAM` user with Role: `BigQuery Data Editor`
In my data set I did `Share dataset` added the user with `Can Edit` privileges.

However when I'm running my script which access BigQuery I get error 403

When I add to my `IAM` user the Role `BigQuery User` The script works.

The scripts runs only `SELECT` query from a table in this data set.

I don't understand why I must grant `BigQuery User` for this to work.

According to the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

> Rationale: The dataEditor role extends bigquery.dataViewer by issuing
>   create, update, delete privileges for the tables within the dataset

`roles/bigquery.dataViewer` has `bigquery.tables.getData` which get table data

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having access to the data and being able to retrieve it with a query are different things and that's where the confusion is coming from.

Per the documentation, [`roles/bigquery.dataEditor`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.dataEditor) has the following permissions:

- Read the dataset's metadata and to list tables in the dataset.
- Create, update, get, and delete the dataset's tables.

This means that the user with this role has access and manipulation rights to the dataset's information and the tables in it. An example would be that a user with this role can see all the table information by navigating to it through the GCP console (schema, details and preview tabs) but when trying to run a query there, the following message will appear:

> Access Denied: Project `<PROJECT-ID>`: The user `<USER>` does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project `<PROJECT-ID>`.

Now let's check the [`roles/bigquery.user`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.user) permissions:

> Permissions to run jobs, including queries, within the project.

The key element here is that the `BigQuery User` role can run jobs and the `BigQuery DataEditor` can't. [BigQuery Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) are the objects that manage the BigQuery tasks, this includes running queries.

With this information, it's clearer in the [roles comparison matrix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#predefined_roles_comparison_matrix) that for what you are trying to accomplish you'll need the `BigQuery DataEditor` role (Get table data/metadata) and the `BigQuery User` role (Create jobs/queries).

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. so dataEditor can run queries from UI but not from scripts?

Comment: No, a `dataEditor` user can see information from the table and its contents in the UI (schema, details and preview) but will not be able to run queries there either. I'll update my answer to clarify that part.

Comment: got same error. but on my side, i can run the query in query editor but not from scripts. what kind of permission do i need?

Comment: This was very informative. I was setting `dataEditor` to a service account and, strangely, it could insert data in the dataset table, even when `does not have bigquery.jobs.create` showed up in the logs. Now I changed to `User`.